# How to get value from Shared preference in Fragment?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have been searching for the correct answer everywhere, but couldn't find it anywhere. That is why I am posting this question, this may look very similar to other questions but I didn't find the answer to this yet. I have to retrieve the user data that was saved during the login on Android device and I want to use the same data in a fragment, I tried using several answers found on StackOverflow, none of them worked for me. Look at the code below, how can I get the user values into strings?

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("mysharedpref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String user_name = preferences.getString("user_id",null);
    String password = preferences.getString("role", null);
```

I have to pass these string values to a URL, but it doesn't work. I also checked passing values manually, it's working. For example, if I take assign values to the above strings like

```
String user_name="admin";
String password="administrator";
```

Comment: how are you setting value in shared preferences ?

Comment: Put your code where you save these strings in shared preference.

Comment: SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, user_id);
        editor.putString(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        editor.putString(KEY_ROLE, role);
        editor.apply();
        return true;

Answer (score 0):

Best way to use your SharedPrefernce is by **using your appContext that is accessible to the whole App(Common SharedPrefernce and accessible Everywhere)**.

**Define your SharedPrefernce instance in your Application class** with **get and set methods** as below : (If you have not created the Application class then create one as below, This class is called at the start of your app)

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {   
    private static Application _instance;   
    private static SharedPreferences _preferences;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
         _instance = this;
    }

    public static Application get() {
        return _instance;
    }

    /**
     * Gets shared preferences.
     *
     * @return the shared preferences
     */
    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences() {
        if (_preferences == null)
            _preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(_instance);
        return _preferences;
    }


//set methods
    public static void setPreferences(String key, String value) {
        getSharedPreferences().edit().putString(key, value).commit();
    }

    public static void setPreferences(String key, long value) {
        getSharedPreferences().edit().putLong(key, value).commit();
    }

    public static void setPreferences(String key, int value) {
        getSharedPreferences().edit().putInt(key, value).commit();
    }

    public static void setPreferencesBoolean(String key, boolean value) {
        getSharedPreferences().edit().putBoolean(key, value).commit();
    }

    //get methods
    public static String getPrefranceData(String key) {
        return getSharedPreferences().getString(key, "");
    }

    public static int getPrefranceDataInt(String key) {
        return getSharedPreferences().getInt(key, 0);
    }

    public static boolean getPrefranceDataBoolean(String key) {
        return getSharedPreferences().getBoolean(key, false);
    }

    public static long getPrefranceDataLong(String interval) {
        return getSharedPreferences().getLong(interval, 0);
    }
}
```

Declare the Application class in AndroidManifest.xml file with line  **android:name=".Application"** as shown in below snippet:

```
<application
            android:name=".Application"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Now, How to store key-value:

```
Application.setPreferences("Key","String_Value");
```

How to fetch key-value:

```
String value_string=Application.getPrefranceData("Key");
```

You can now **set-SharedPrefernce key-value** and **get-SharedPrefernce value** from anywhere in the app using **public Application class** and the **static get and set methods**

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to get values with different key. Get values with same key you put them with.

```
String user_name = preferences.getString(preferences.KEY_USERNAME,null);
String password = preferences.getString(preferences.KEY_PASSWORD, null);
```

**----BUT----**

And don't use singleton pattern for SharedPreferences it is very bad to use Context in singleton. It will crash your app. You can figure it out why.

Instead use static methods.

```
public class PreferenceUtil {

public static final String PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";


public static void setInt(Context context, int in, String key) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    Editor editor;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();

    editor.putInt(key, in);

    editor.apply();

}


public static int getInt(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (settings.contains(key)) {
        return settings.getInt(key, 0);
    } else
        return 0;
}

}
```

And access it like this

```
int password = PreferenceUtil.getInt(getActivity(), PreferenceUtil.PASSWORD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a SharedPreference.java Class.

```
 public class SharedPreference {
    Context context;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    String user_name;
    String password;

    public SharedPreference(Context co) {
        context = co;
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        password = getStringInput("password");
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
        stringInput("password", password);
    }

    public String getUser_name() {
        user_name = getStringInput("Username");
        return user_name;
    }

    public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
        this.user_name = user_name;
        stringInput("Username", user_name);
    }

    public void stringInput(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getStringInput(String key) {
        return sharedPreferences.getString(key, "0");
    }
}
```

Now go into activity or Fragment 
example: I'm gone use it in MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Prefrences prefrences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Dashboard");

    prefrences = new Prefrences(MainActivity.this);
    prefrences.setUser_name("Rishabh Jain");
    prefrences.setUser_name("8369554235");

    Log.e("Details",prefrences.getUser_name()+" "+prefrences.getPassword())
     }
    }
```

The output will be Rishabh Jain 8369554235.
Similarly, you can use this in any Activity or any Fragment